# How do you hide the folders in your websites public_html folder?

Tags: permissions, webserver

I don't like how if you go to certain folders on my website that don't contain a .html file that it will list all the files in it. I don't want to give access to that. Such as: http://christianselig.com/css

How do I hide these?

Comment: Possible duplicate question, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610524/htaccess-to-restrict-access-to-folder

Comment: @bodi0 Nope, that is a different topic… `Options -Indexes` is what the OP is searching for (provided that he/she is using Apache).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Apache webserver and have access to httpd.conf you can set "Options -Indexes" for directory which content you want to hide.
If you have no access to httpd.conf you can create .htaccess file in directory which content you want to hide  with "IndexIgnore *"

Comment: As of the Apache documentation `Options` is also editable via `.htaccess`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell your webserver to stop directory listings. For apache, add this to your httpd.conf or any other related config file

```
<Directory /path/to/directory>
   Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

If placed in a .htaccess file, `AllowOverride Options` must be enabled for the desired directory.