# "Disabling" folder with WAMP / Joomla

Tags: apache, joomla, wamp

I'm curious about a WAMP + Joomla feature...

On my project folder and within /www/, I have several Joomla folders that are accessible (features inside are usable) but when directly opened from the Web browser show no contents (but no error message is shown)... This is a behaviour I would like to make other folders have but I don't seem to be able to get it!

Let me explain a but further, folder called "CLI" if opened in web browser as:

.../components

returns a blank screen... But some of my modules are using content within, so folder is not restricted but contents are not visible through Web brower.

Now I have another folder:

.../clients

Which I would need to behave the same way as many modules of my site need this, but I can't afford to leave it "open" for users (if someone enters ".../clients" on their web browser, I need the output to be blank, same as the .../components folder above). Currently, if someone enters .../clients on a web browser, they can see all files within, this is a CRITICAL security bug for me.

I've succeeded to disable them by doing DENY FROM ALL in httpd.conf. However, this is not valid as it absolutely restricts everything within the folder, causing my modules to crash.

Hope you get the point, if not, happy to clarify :)

MANY MANY THANKS for your support!!!

PS - If possible, answer in a dummy way as I'm new to all of this Apache stuff.

Comment: You should read about .htaccess file.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610524/htaccess-to-restrict-access-to-folder

Answer (score 1):

The way Joomla returns a blank screen is by adding a blank index.html file in. Browsers prioritise a index.html file to display over the index.php file etc. So literally put in a index.html file in the subfolder containing:

```
<html>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Lodder if you look in the components folder for example, you'll see it had the code I posted originally. However for reference this will work as well