# htaccess to block direct access to folder (exception: via php)

Tags: .htaccess

How do I use htaccess to set folder access "deny by default" with 2 exceptions.

Folder named www.mydomain.com/SecretFolder/ to "deny by default".

2 exceptions:
1) SecretFolder accepts only www.mydomain.com/Allowed.php to access into it.
2) Inside the SecretFolder, there is a file, named Exception.php that's not blocked and always accessible even directly

Would this cause looping?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610524/htaccess-to-restrict-access-to-folder?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this code?

```
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files Allowed.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

It should deny access to any file except from localhost, and the second should allow the file you wanted access for.

Also check if check if mod_access in installed on your server.

Comment: What should i replace that 127.0.0.1 with? Can i also redirect the access via Allowed.php if the folder gets a direct access?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 should be the default local access