# Best way to protect php files of your website

Tags: php, android

I have some ideas to solve this situation, but still wanted to ask someone with more experience.

I've created an Android App that makes requests to some URL. In this URL I would also like to have the landing page of my app. Howevere, I don't want people to enter to my folders where I process the requests (I have there some interface to test my app). When I protect this folder with a password via cPanel, the users are not avaible to connect with my php files and download the data. What is the best way to handle this? Should I have two URL (one for the landing page - one for the backend)? Should I not create any link to my backend files and not allow Google to crawl them? Should I add a password to this folder and insert the Username and Password in my client?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the folder contain php files that you need to access only by the Android client?

Comment: Yes, it does. I think I´m going to create an empty index.php! Since .htaccess file could prevent the client (the users of the android app) to connect with my php files, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either add .htaccess file [here is apache link how to configure it](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) or add empty index.html or index.php files in each folder.

Comment: I like the idea of adding an empty index. And then I could rename the interface I use to test my app (now is the Index) and protect it with a password

Answer (score 0):

If you add an .htaccess file with:

```
deny from all
```

It will give a 403 error to any visitors and therefore not display the folders!

(See this page: [.htaccess to restrict access to folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610524/htaccess-to-restrict-access-to-folder))