# Magento SKIN and VAR Folder Permission

Tags: php, database, magento, zend-framework, cpanel

My site is based on magento and i want to know how can i stop someone to access my server through URL BAR like this:

www.mydomain.com/skin/

if someone types this on URL bar it open up my server files etc which is not secure the file permission for this SKIN folder is 755 in my cpanel.

The other folder is VAR folder for this the file permission is also 755 but we cannot access this through URL BAR like this
www.mydomain.com/VAR/

as it gives this Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /var on this server.

I want this same for my SKIN Folder too but when i change permission of SKIN folder to 644 my site css files do not load and site comes up all messed up but if i make it 755 site is super fine but directory is accessible through URL bar .

How can i keep 755 permission to SKIN folder but it should not be accessible through URL Bar.

Comment: Use .htaccess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610524/htaccess-to-restrict-access-to-folder

Answer (score 1):

You should not turn off access to /skin.  If you do your site will not render any of its frontend content.  You can, however, turn off directory indexing if you're trying to keep people from seeing what's in the directories.  See [How do I disable directory browsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530372/how-do-i-disable-directory-browsing).

Note, however, that if you are trying to hide something from people browsing your site the /skin directory is the wrong place to put it.

Comment: This site is also based in magento
https://www.transfashions.com

and see here his skin folder is not accessible and site is rendering fine.

https://www.transfashions.com/skin/

Comment: That's because they are doing exactly what I noted above :-).  The /skin directory is accessible; there are /skin contents on the page to test this against.  However, they disabled directory browsing, as noted in my answer, which gives the 403 when looking at the directory.

Another thing they do is use CSS/JS concatenation which puts the CSS/JS in the writable /media directory instead of /skin.  But /skin is still accessible, but not browsable.

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess file rewrite rule is not working.

I had same issue and i fixed below way.

If your Apache version > 2.2 then

Open .htaccess and find around RewriteEngine on

```
          Options +FollowSymLinks
```

and replace with

```
            Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
```

Answer (score -1):

One Relative solution is create one index.html file in your skin folder. 
Now your skin folder won't be directly accessible.

We can also prevent directory listing with .htaccess like var folder.
But if you will do with .htaccess then your skin files won't be accessible.So better option is create one index.html file or index.php file with appropriate error message.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This site is also based in magento
https://www.transfashions.com

and see here his skin folder is not accessible and site is rendering fine.

https://www.transfashions.com/skin/

Comment: They might have kept index.php with this message.

Comment: what is drawback to put index.php or index.html in skin folder ? it wont allow to show directory content